# Finding specific digit pattern with regex in python

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I want to replace all values in a dataframe column that starts with "-99." using regex with `NaN` as these are the outliers.

I used `df['Item'].replace(r(^[-][9][9]\d.*$),np.NaN)` but it did not work.

Comment: is the number 3 digits long? I don't know pandas well but possibly try r'^[-][9][9]\d.*$' instead of r(^[-][9][9]\d.*$). the r before a string indicates a raw string, I haven't seen it before a parentheses before. Do you have a sample string it should and shouldn't match to we can see?

Comment: What is the dtype of the columns?

Comment: @MindFlow I undid some of your edits. Please don't use `code formatting` for stuff which isn't code.

Comment: @MindFlow Thanks for the suggestion. This is my first question on StackOverflow; I made a mistake.

Comment: @jlandercy type of column is float64

Comment: I have found a workaround to replace outliers with NaN with .loc option. So for now my program works functionally. However, I wasn't able to solve it with regex.

Comment: Regexp work on str not float or int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

The regular expression posted by `@tripleee` is fine to detect numbers (encoded as string) starting with `-99.` The problem here is you are dealing with number and regular expression are only suited for string.

### MCVE

Lets build a comprehensive example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([-999, -99.9, -9, 9, 99.9, 0., 1, -999], columns=['Item'])

    Item
0 -999.0
1  -99.9
2   -9.0
3    9.0
4   99.9
5    0.0
6    1.0
7 -999.0
```

#### Regular Expression

Then you can [`match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) outliers using the regular expression (provided the string format is suitable for), then all you need is to cast ([`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)) into string before applying regular expression (which resides in [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html) toolsuite of Series).

```
q1 = df['Item'].astype(str).str.match(r'^-99\..*')

0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
```

But if you intend to replace those value by `nan` using the replace function of string object then it will requires extra steps as this [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) function expect another string and nothing else (using `np.nan` or `None` will fail). Then you will have to execute:

```
df['Item'].astype(str).str.replace(r'^-99\..*', 'nan').astype(float)
```

IMO this is a pretty bad one-liner because of "unnecessary" casting which spoils the very nature of your data.

#### Logical Indexing

You better go for [logical indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) using the boolean vector above, either by replacing by sentinel:

```
df.loc[q1] = np.nan

    Item
0 -999.0
1    NaN
2   -9.0
3    9.0
4   99.9
5    0.0
6    1.0
7 -999.0
```

or slicing:

```
df = df.loc[~q1,:]

    Item
0 -999.0
2   -9.0
3    9.0
4   99.9
5    0.0
6    1.0
7 -999.0
```

Anyway converting number into string to detect outlier seems a bit odd (poor performance, complex behaviour hard to debug, extra copy of data).

### Float Arithmetic

#### Simple filter

If there is no reason that numbers less than `-99.` are still valid, then you can filter them out using a simple numerical criterion:

```
q2 = df['Item'] <= -99.
df = df.loc[~q2,:]

   Item
2  -9.0
3   9.0
4  99.9
5   0.0
6   1.0
```

Which will perform way better and avoid to cast numbers to string and *vice versa*. It also avoid the need of extra copy of data (string, then float again, then overwrite initial data). So it will be both memory (copy of data) and computationally (regular expression are intensive) efficient with regards to your first choice.

#### Epsilon ball filter

If numbers less than the cut off must be kept then you can still perform it with float arithmetic. Just change the *less than* criterion for an *epsilon ball* criterion around the desired value. To capture all numbers within `[-100., -99.]` you can use the following setup:

```
target = -99.5
epsilon = 0.5
q3 = np.abs(df['Item'] - target) <= epsilon

0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
```

Off course you can change the `target` and make `epsilon` as small as possible with regard to your machine precision.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer, and I really thought that regex would be a better option though your explanation gives me a better understanding now why it won't be a good choice. I did end up using the `temperature.loc[temperature.MAX_TEMP < -90, 'MAX_TEMP'] = np.nan` condition and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno about Pandas, but the code you show lacks quotes, and of course the regex doesn't do what you say you want to do. `\d*.$` says it has to *end* with a digit followed by any character. Probably you mean

```py
df['Item'].replace(r'^-99\..*',np.NaN)
```

where the `^` anchor means beginning of line (or, here, beginning of the cell) and `-99` just matches literal text. Finally `\.` matches a literal dot, and `.*` matches anything after that, up until the end of the cell.

Comment: That particular value is an outlier value in the column that starts with -99. followed by more digits. I want to replace it with NaN and which then will be replaced by the mean value of the column for the NaN. I am new to pandas and regex not able to figure it out to match digits using regex.

Comment: If your data are numbers then regex is almost certainly the wrong tool. You'd have to convert each to a string and then use a regex on that; but for numeric operations, that's insane -- just check if it's less than -99 (or bigger than -100, but if these are outliers as you say, that's probably not necessary).  Doing regex on numbers only makes sense if you want to look for genuinely textual patterns, like check if every second digit is the same number or something like that.